# Reading a single line with node readline

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to read a single line from an input stream, and then another line, but without saving the readline interface.  Is this possible?

```
import readline from 'readline'

function readSingleLine(prefix) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const rl = readline.createInterface({ 
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout,
    })
    rl.on('line', (line) => {
      console.log(prefix, line)
      rl.close()
      resolve()
    })
  })
}
  
async function main() {
  await readSingleLine('A')
  await readSingleLine('B')
}   
    
await main()
```

With that code and this command:

```
node run.mjs <<EOF
test1
test2
test3
EOF
```

I get

```
test1
A test1
```

I assume that this is because even though the first interface closes, the stream empties before I manage to pause it; is that correct?  What's the right way to do what I want here...abandon the readline module and read everything in a character at a time?